# Aptana 3 php can't activate function linking and variable assist

Tags: php, autocomplete, aptana

I just upgraded to Aptana 3 and seem to have lost some of the great functionality I had in Eclipse. So far I can't figure out how to re-enable it.

Specifically, I need these 2 functions turned back on:

```
FileUpload::checkForExistingUploadPath('./somepath');
```

Previously, hovering over the 'checkForExistingUploadPath' path would hyperlink it and I could jump straight to that function in that class. It still hightlights the 'FileUpload' part, but not the function. It won't even jump to functions within the same class.

The other part is letting me know what variables are used by that function. Previously you could hover over 'checkForExistingUploadPath' and it would say

```
checkForExistingUploadPath($var1, $var2 = true, $etc);
```

i.e it provided the variable names and order.

Any help on switching these back on would be appreciated - and I'm sure that particular preference has other goodies I need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to work on a project that was created or re-defined as Aptana PHP project. Doing so enables the advanced features you are looking for.

In case you are creating a new project, use the Aptana PHP project wizard.

In case you already have projects in your workspace, you'll have to add the 'Aptana PHP Nature' to your project:

- Right-click on the project in the Project Explorer View.
- Choose Properties > Project Natures.
- Select the PHP nature (the one with the icon).
- Click OK. It will ask to close and reopen your project.

This should do it (and if it doesn't, restart the studio).

Hope that helps!