# How can I browse through my PHP code in Aptana?

Tags: php, hyperlink, navigation, aptana

When I was developing Java with Eclipse in the old days, I remember that I could click on each method and Class which brought me to the according place, where that specific method is defined. Even in third party libraries.

Now in Aptana, I can only click on and browse to my PHP class method names that exist in the very current file I am working in. But I cannot click on any Class name or method that exists externally in other files.

Is this a not yet implemented (or even not yet planned) feature of Aptana? Or can I simply activate extensive browsing to external files as well?

Sidenote: I am always working with [FQDN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fully_qualified_domain_name)s.

Comment: Try `ctrl + click` or use `F3`

Comment: As described in my question: I can `ctrl + click` on methods I have locally defined. But nothing that's not in my very current file.

Comment: `F3` should work for external files. I just checked in Aptana Studio 3.4 and its working for me. `ctrl + click` is also working for me.

Comment: `Aptana Studio 3, build: 3.4.1.201306062137`. When exactly you hit `F3`? Where do you place the cursor (I suppose on the to be browsed element)?

Comment: Yes over the method name to browse.

Comment: Doesn't work in my case. Curious...

Comment: My current build is `build: 3.4.2.201308081805`. There might be some problem with the installation. You can try reinstalling it.

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8090204/1828051) did it. (Project nature wasn't set to PHP.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Project Nature wasn't set to PHP for this project. I changed it according [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8090204/1828051):

1. Right-click on the project in the Project Explorer View.
2. Choose `Properties > Project Natures`.
3. Select `PHP nature`.
4. Confirm and re-open project.